# Duplicate class caused by Android Gradle plugin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I'm having some trouble with Gradle and Android Studio. When trying to compile the dependency `com.nukkitx.protocol:bedrock-v407:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT` I'm getting duplicate class errors, but when compiled in a normal desktop Gradle project it compiles fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code: https://github.com/rtm516/GeyserAndroid

Error:

```
Duplicate class it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints.IntIterator found in modules jetified-fastutil-common-8.3.1.jar (com.nukkitx.fastutil:fastutil-common:8.3.1) and jetified-fastutil-int-common-8.3.1.jar (com.nukkitx.fastutil:fastutil-int-common:8.3.1)
Duplicate class it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.LongIterator found in modules jetified-fastutil-common-8.3.1.jar (com.nukkitx.fastutil:fastutil-common:8.3.1) and jetified-fastutil-long-common-8.3.1.jar (com.nukkitx.fastutil:fastutil-long-common:8.3.1)
Duplicate class it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.ObjectIterator found in modules jetified-fastutil-common-8.3.1.jar (com.nukkitx.fastutil:fastutil-common:8.3.1) and jetified-fastutil-object-common-8.3.1.jar (com.nukkitx.fastutil:fastutil-object-common:8.3.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by using https://github.com/shevek/jarjar and removing the duplicate classes using the below.

```
implementation jarjar.repackage {
    from 'com.nukkitx.fastutil:fastutil-common:8.3.1'

    classDelete "it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.ints.IntIterator"
    classDelete "it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.LongIterator"
    classDelete "it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.ObjectIterator"
}
```